# Função não retorna valor

Tags: php, mysql

Colegas...

tenho um método do qual traz os resultados de uma tabela. Até aqui tudo bem. O que está me intrigando é que depois que mudei de servidor, a estrutura desse método é a mesma para outros dois resultados e funcionam perfeitamente, porém ao criar outro método com a mesma estrutura, não retorna valor, a não ser quando só tem um só valor no banco. Já copiei e colei a estrutura do método funcional, substituindo somente o nome do método e nada. Porém quando dou echo em vez do return, aparece o resultado. Diante disso, isolei o código em um outro arquivo e em um exemplo simples, o erro aparece. Vejam em uma função simples:

```
function teste(){
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
            $c = $i;
        } 
  return $c;  
} 
echo teste();
```

O resultado aparece apenas o 9. Porém quando dou um echo. Retorna os valores corretamente:

```
function teste(){
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $c = $i;
        echo $c;
    }
}
echo teste();
```

Alguém sabe o porque isso acontece?

Comment: Algumas das respostas lhe foi útil? se não poste o que não funcionou poste o que ainda esta acontecendo se sim valide uma resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para retornar todos os valores concatene uma string usando o operador `.=`, dessa forma a cada iteração do for a variável `$c` recebera o valor já contido mais o atual. Caso você necessite fazer algum calculo ou formatação nesses valores é melhor guarda isso em um array.

Versão com string:

```
function teste(){
   $c = '';
   for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
      $c .= $i .' ';
   }
   return $c;
}
```

Versão com array:

```
<?php
    function teste(){
       $c = array();
       for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
          $c[] = $i; 
       }
       return $c;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(teste());
```

Answer (score 6):

Tem em conta que o `return` só vai ser chamado depois de o `for` ter corrido.

Ou seja, o ciclo `for` vai correr na integra, o valor de `$c` vai sendo re-escrito até o ciclo acabar. Aí, quando o ciclo acaba, o ultimo valor que `$c` tem é 9 e é esse valor que vai ser passado ao `return`.

Quando juntas um `echo` dentro do ciclo `for` estás a registar (fazer echo) de cada valor que o `$i` toma e que passa ao `$c`, daí a diferênça. O resultado final é o mesmo, o retornado pelo `return` é o mesmo. Repara que na versão com o `echo` dentro do ciclo `for` tens de certeza 2 vezes o numero `9`, a segunda o `return` da função.

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio

Answer (score 4):

Nesta função esta retornando somente o ultimo valor do vetor. pois o for ficara atribuindo até chegar ao fim do vetor, e quando chegar irá retornar o ultimo valor atribuído a `$c`

```
function teste(){
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
            $c = $i;
        } 
  return $c;  
} 
echo teste();
```

Nesta outra esta imprimindo o valor de `$c` a cada novo ciclo do `for`.

```
function teste(){
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $c = $i;
        echo $c;
    }
}
echo teste();
```

Nesta esta a atribuir a um array e imprimindo todo o conteúdo:

```
function teste(){
    $c = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $c[] = $i;
    }
    return $c;
}
var_dump(teste());
```

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo.